# API as an engine: Can't get factories to work in my rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rails-engines

I've built an api as a mountable engine, and am currently having trouble setting up factory girl.

Take this factory for instance:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    ...
  end
end
```

When I call FactoryGirl.create(:client) in my rspec test I get the error 'Uninitialized Constant Client'. There is no Client model in engines/api/app/models, however there is a Client model in the app the api is mounted on. I tried namespacing it to that app, ie:

```
factory :client, class: 'MyApp::Client' do
```

but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

In my api controllers when I do something like Client.new or Client.create it seems to magically work with the app its mounted on, but I get the feeling there's something big I'm missing to get this to work with tests.

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/issues/99
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/194
maybe these will help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be because the rspec can resove the proper class to include, so you can explicitly require the file with model class, and so you'll get:

**spec/factories/client.rb**:

```
require_relative '../../app/models/client.rb'

factory :client, class: MyApp::Client do
   #...
end
```